# Directions and Directions Panel not showing up for google API

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

## Maps API - Getting Directions not working!

My directions is not showing up alongside my map. I have followed both the API and many examples thoroughly and it seems that I am doing everything correctly. (i believe that the directions should show up using mainly three line of code following "directionsService.route()). I have a web app which will generate both a map and directions once the submit button on the bottom of the is clicked. The directions should be on the right and the map on the left, my map is working fine but the directions will not even show up. Maybe something is overwriting the directions panel, causing it to not display?

My code is below. Please help, I have been looking at the code for so long, everything is starting to look the same lol :)

P.s., I am new to the Google MAPS Api and Stackoverflow :)

Please help, I, and many others who are implementing a webapp like this would GREATLY appreciate this!

Thanks in advance!

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Waypoints in directions</title>

<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  #panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }
</style>
<style>
  #directions-panel {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    width: 390px;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  #map-canvas {
    margin-right: 400px;
  }

  @media print {
    #map-canvas {
      height: 500px;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #directions-panel {
      float: none;
      width: auto;
    }
  }
}
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var douglasville = new google.maps.LatLng(33.751497,-84.747714);

function initialize() {
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
   var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
   var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 6,
   center: douglasville
   }

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
   directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

   var rendererOptions = {
        map: map
   }
}

function calcRoute() {
   var start = "3557 doris circle douglasville, ga 30135";
   var end = "421 st marlow dr. lawrenceville, ga 30044";
   var waypts = [];
   var checkboxArray = ["4899 Chapel Hill rd douglasville, ga 30135", "120 North avenue      nw atlanta, ga 30332", "275 Riverside Pkwy SW, Austell, GA 30168"]
   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
       waypts.push({
           location:checkboxArray[i],
           stopover:true});
   }
   var request = {
       origin: start,
       destination: end,
       waypoints: waypts,
       optimizeWaypoints: true,
       travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
   };
   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }else{
          alert("something went wrong!");
       }
 });
}


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="directions_panel"></div>
    <div id="map-canvas" ></div>
    <div style="margin:20px;border-width:2px;"><br>
      <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue in this line:

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
```

Element in your document has id **directions_panel**, not **directions-panel**.